# Porting content the efficient way!

Tags: content-manager, content-porter-2013

Is it possible to have a packet with all components and pages in export package and then just importing all the pages(which should automatically be resolving all the missing reference as all components are already there in the package) ?

I just tried the traditional way, which is first exporting the component and then the pages. Well lets just say that it is taking forever to resolve dependencies, and separately importing localized version.

Also what steps I can follow to have all the localized versions of both component and pages as well?

Answer (score 3):

I'd question the work 'just' in your post.

When you say

> all components and pages

then the quantity and complexity very quickly becomes a core question.

Also, I'd suggest it's important to make the point here that it doesn't automatically mean the tool is at fault just because a process takes a long time (although I accept it would be much more useful if we had better/any visibility of that CP was doing at any point in time).

Content Porter (and with that, I mean the associated ImportExport Service) is performing some pretty complex checks when resolving dependencies; not just checking if a component needs including as it's on a page - but (depending on your settings), the schemas being used, that the fields in the component XML match to the schema fields at that point in time and much much more)

How complex is your content model for the items your are importing/exporting?
What's the level of localization?
What the complexity of the Blueprint structure?
What items are you asking Content Porter to dependency check?

If you're looking to move from Content Porter to an app utilising the ImportExport service you're still going to have to understand the content you're moving to best understand how to help the service work most efficiently.

I often find that it real-world scenarios a client will expect you to truly understand the content/assets you are moving through Content Porter and expect **you** to manage the dependencies - thus allowing you to create a port for Keywords, Schemas, Components and **then** Templates and then Pages etc.

I'd suggest posting some of your Content Porter settings, perhaps indicate what amount of content you're pushing and the level of nesting within it etc. Then we may be able to spot some simple, quick fixes to assist.

Comment: yeah, in most cases editors just select export everything and then complain why it takes long. like exporting thousand of pages and components is fast :D

Comment: Also, may be looking at Paul's post here on using Content Porter with release management.... http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/content-porting-migrating-environments-without-headaches

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes. You can use ImportExport service to export data the way you need it and import also. Please make notice that content porter in background connects to same service. The advantage here is that you can automate activities like exporting pages based on criteria and impprting them in bulk or in steps. But good thing is that tool does it for you.